# How to change php -s access log/output format

Tags: php

I have a development PHP server running the `php -S` command in docker and I would like to change the access log/output format. I would like to include some more details, like the http method etc. I've been trying to find some details about it online, but it seems not possible. I've checked the `php.ini` file and it contains no such configuration.
Is it even possible?

I am using php 5.6.

Thanks

Comment: From the look of [the code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5eb1f92f31cafc48384f9096012f421b37f6d425/sapi/cli/php_cli_server.c#L1128) the output seems to be hardcoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log of `php -S` is produced by the function [`php_cli_server_log_response()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/fdd9f572dafdfb739c20de169832f659a87fdbad/sapi/cli/php_cli_server.c#L1089) defined in [`sapi/cli/php_cli_server.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/fdd9f572dafdfb739c20de169832f659a87fdbad/sapi/cli/php_cli_server.c) at line [1098](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/fdd9f572dafdfb739c20de169832f659a87fdbad/sapi/cli/php_cli_server.c#L1089).

It uses hard-coded formats to display [the remote IP address, response status code and the request URI](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/fdd9f572dafdfb739c20de169832f659a87fdbad/sapi/cli/php_cli_server.c#L1128), followed by a [message](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/fdd9f572dafdfb739c20de169832f659a87fdbad/sapi/cli/php_cli_server.c#L1135) and an [error message that includes the file path and the line number](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/fdd9f572dafdfb739c20de169832f659a87fdbad/sapi/cli/php_cli_server.c#L1144), if the script was terminated because of an unhandled runtime error.

There is currently no way to change the format using `php.ini` or the command line. You can, however, fork your own copy of PHP, change its code and compile it on your system.